# Sharing a Background Image Across Multiple View Controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, background, uiimageview

I am building an app in Swift using Xcode. I have a set of `5 images` which I want to use as a background on all of my view controllers.

I have `10+  View Controllers`, but I want to be able to reuse the images.

Generally I would add an image view to all of my view controllers, and set the image.

I would use a public variable to change what image is being shown. But on this app, I have many view controllers, and it wouldn't be very efficient to create each and every image view.

Is there a way I can do it faster? Thanks.

Comment: you can use container view to reuse same image in every view controller.... or can make a global image variable which can be set to every image view in each view controller

Comment: Many ways to do, u can create UIView with a .Xib then just set it as background of all the VC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way of doing this with swift when compared to subclassing, write an extension and call your method in all your view controllers.

```
extension UIViewController{

func setCustomBackgroundImage(){

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"yourImageFromXcAssets")!)

    //or

    let bgImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "yourImageFromXcAssets"))
    self.view.addSubview(bgImage)
}
}
```

and in your view controllers just call it like regular UIViewController class methods,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setCustomBackgroundImage()
}
```

or write a category over UIViewController with Objective-C

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (customBackground)

- (void)setCustomBackgroundImage;

@end

#import "UIViewController+customBackground.h"

@implementation UIViewController (customBackground)

- (void)setCustomBackgroundImage{
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageFromXcAssets"]]];
    //or
    UIImageView *bgImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageFromXcAssets"]];
    bgImage.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:bgImage];
}

@end
```

And the same approach with Objective C as well,

```
 [self setCustomBackgroundImage];
```

I am using a view controller extension to manage all my styles, colors and appearances across my app.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass all 10+ viewcontroller(s) with a Parent ViewController.

> @interface ViewController : ParentViewController

Call a method from *viewDidLoad* of ParentViewController.

> // ParentViewController
>
> -(void)viewDidLoad {
>
> [self createBackgroundView];
>
> }

Inside createBackgroundView, programmatically create UIImageView, and populate it using a public variable (as per your requirement).

Inside your ViewController's viewDidLoad, call [super viewDidLoad];

> // One of your 10+ ViewController(s)
>
> -(void)viewDidLoad {
>
> [super viewDidLoad];
>
> // rest of your code
>
> }

Comment: How do I create a ParentViewController? Also, how can I make sure that the background image is behind all of the others items?

Comment: Any ViewController would extend UIViewController. So instead of that, make it to extend ParentViewController. ParentViewController would extend UIViewController. 

When you define something in viewDidLoad, it would be called first. So your backgroundView will be behind of all other views.I can share sample code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a set of global variables in a class:

```
class Images {
    static let image1 = UIImage(named: "image1.png")
    static let image2 = UIImage(named: "image2.png")
    static let image3 = UIImage(named: "image3.png")
    static let image4 = UIImage(named: "image4.png")
    static let image5 = UIImage(named: "image5.png")

    static var selectedImage = image1
}
```

Now to select the image,

```
Images.selectedImage = Images.image3
```

To set background, in each VC, set:

```
imageView.image = Images.selectedImage
```